# How to convert dataframe with strings into ndarray on Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, rust-polars, rust-ndarray

I'm facing with problem using `Rust` for converting `Polars DataFrame` with string values into `ndarray` without One Hot Encoding.

The example of code I used is the following:

```rust
println!("{:?}", _df.to_ndarray::<Float64Type>(Default::default()).unwrap());
```

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `apply` method and iterate over each column in the DataFrame and convert it to a numeric representation.so the resulting DataFrame, `df_numeric`, will have numeric values instead of strings and finally use the `to_ndarray` method to convert the DataFrame to an ndarray, and the resulting ndarray, `ndarray`, will have `Option` type to handle missing values.

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use ndarray::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    //make a Polars DataFrame with string values
    let df = DataFrame::new(vec![
        Series::new("col1", &["a", "b", "c"]),
        Series::new("col2", &["x", "y", "z"]),
    ])
    .unwrap();

    //converting string columns to numeric representation
    let df_numeric = df.apply(|s: &Series| s.utf8().unwrap().as_ref().map(|v| v.get(0) as u32));

    //converting the DataFrame to an ndarray
    let ndarray: Array2<Option<u32>> = df_numeric
        .to_ndarray::<UInt32Type>(Default::default())
        .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", ndarray);
}
```